# How catch mouse wheel up/down events using GTK3?

Tags: c, gtk3, mousewheel

how do I implement mouse wheel up/down events using C GTK3?

I have adapted this [code](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/) in order to handle mouse scoll events:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
  int count;
  double coordx[100];
  double coordy[100];
} glob;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{
  do_drawing(cr);

  return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.count - 1; i++ ) {
      for (j = 0; j <= glob.count - 1; j++ ) {
          cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[i], glob.coordy[i]);
          cairo_line_to(cr, glob.coordx[j], glob.coordy[j]);
      }
  }

  glob.count = 0;
  cairo_stroke(cr);    
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    if (event->button == 1) {
        glob.coordx[glob.count] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[glob.count++] = event->y;
    }

    if (event->button == 3) {
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static gboolean mouse_scroll (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
               {

    printf("scrolled up! \n");



                     return TRUE;  
               }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  glob.count = 0;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_SCROLL_MASK);


  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

        g_signal_connect(window, "scroll-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(mouse_scroll), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

However, this only catches a general mouse event, irrespective of whether the mouse is scrolled up or down. I want to know how can I get it to **printf("scrolled up! \n")** only when the mouse wheel is scrolled up. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*event` parameter in `mouse_scroll` should point to [`GdkEventScroll`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventScroll) structure which has `direction` member:

> `GdkScrollDirection direction;` the direction to scroll to (one of
>   `GDK_SCROLL_UP`, `GDK_SCROLL_DOWN`, `GDK_SCROLL_LEFT`,
>   `GDK_SCROLL_RIGHT` or `GDK_SCROLL_SMOOTH`).